# Remote Desktop to a specific server works on one computer but not on another

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

(Also posted on StackOverflow and SuperUser)

I am finally switching from a desktop to a laptop at work.

I use Remote Desktop quite a bit to access our server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard).

I can access the server from the desktop (Windows 7 Enterprise, 32 bit), but when I try from the new laptop (Windows 7 Enterprise, 64 bit), I get past the login screen and then I keep seeing the `Configuring remote session...` message continuously and the Remote Desktop session never starts.

I have admin access on all devices so that's not the issue.

I don't have problems with the firewall when using other computers with my account.

I did a little research but nothing I've read seems to relate to my situation. I have tried the following:

- Renaming `%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe` to `mstsc.OLD` and running the 32 bit mstsc from `%windir%\SysWOW64\mstsc.exe` but didn't have any luck.
- Connecting FROM the server TO the laptop works fine.
- Created a batch file with the following and still no luck:

  ```
  @echo off
  set WinDir=
  start C:WindowsSysWow64mstsc.exe
  ```

Comment: What about trying the version under C:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe instead of Syswow folder?

Comment: The version in system32 is actually the 64 bit version.  The one in SysWOW64 is the 32 bit version.  Counterintuitive, but that's the way Microsoft set it up.

Comment: Yep.. did you try it?

Comment: No...when you run the 32 bit (without renaming the 64 bit), it actually closes and runs the 64 bit by default.  But I'll give it a shot anyway.

Comment: @BobStout aah .. didn't know that bit :)

Comment: @Aaron:  The laptop does have SP1.  Didn't see that until you asked.

Comment: Can you connect via RDP to another server instead of that one?

Comment: @esserafael:  No.  Can't connect to the desktop that I was using before the laptop, anyway.

Comment: @Aceth:  No joy on using the mstsc in /windows/system32, either.

Comment: Any local firewall's on the laptop? e.g. mcafee (I HATE that thing)?

Comment: @Aceth:  Not that I'm aware of.  Regardless, the firewall settings are controlled via group policy and it should be the same policy on the laptop as is on the desktop (that I can connect with).

Comment: Is your DNS server set correctly?
Can you ping those servers from your laptop?
If your firewall is controlled via GPO, verify if isn't something different there..
Try disabling all local resources when connecting with mstsc

Comment: I believe so, since I can connect via the desktop, and connect TO the laptop from both the server and the desktop.

Comment: I mean the DNS servers configured on your laptop, checking if it is getting the right addresses..

Comment: @esserafael:  Doing IPCONFIG, it looks the same as the desktop.  However, when one of our network guys comes back from lunch, I'll confirm that the DNS servers are configured correctly with him.

Comment: @esserafael:  We use DHCP instead of DNS, according to our tech.  So, according to him, it's not a factor in the problem.

Comment: Is NLA required on the server? Is your new laptop set to RDP using NLA? If you don't/can't answer that, then I suggest you contact your IT guy.

Comment: A little tangent - what do you mean by "DHCP instead of DNS" - they aren't comparable :\

Comment: But DHCP and DNS are two different things, maybe your tech meant that the DHCP automatically configures DNS settings on your laptop.

Comment: @out-null:  No, NLA is not required.

Comment: @esserafael:  Exactly what he meant.

Comment: None of the Questions here would have anything to do with a connection freezing after login. Did you guys read the Question? Bob, is your Laptop upgraded to the latest [RDP Client](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592687) and are all Windows Updates installed (check in the control panel)?

Comment: Yes I read, now I realized the "Configuring remote session" part is after the credentials, in my mind I was thinking about it before, so it could be connection/name resolution problem.

In the mstsc, try unchecking everything in Local Resources tab, like printers, drivers, etc. And in Remote Audio Settings select "Do not play" and "Do not record". Then test what happens.

Comment: @ChrisS:  I'm missing one update (per our techs, no biggie, doesn't involve RDP).  Also have the latest RDP Client.

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Comment: @Aceth:  No, I haven't.  Quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the audio driver that was causing the problem.  I deleted the RealTek driver that was being used and used the generic windows one, and was able to connect with Remote Desktop with no issues.

Comment: On which machine? The client or the server?

Comment: On the client machine.